# Zend Framework display JavaScript Alert Box on Loading a form

Tags: zend-framework

Hi can anyone tell me how I can get a JavaScript alert to display on loading a form in the zend framework

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. You loading your form using ajax?

Comment: @Marcin Sorry asked this one about 3am in the morning, I mean when the form loads I would like a simple JS alert box to display no ajax required. I've looked at this but most onload JS functions appear to be linked to the body tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the `</form>` tag, simply add:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert('Your Message Here');
</script>
```

Comment: sorry for the delay getting back to you my BB was down, my form is actually a class that is called in its associated .phtml file. I will try adding your code to the file after the call to the form.

Comment: This works thanks sorry for the delay my connection is still flaky